# Are these two arguments incompatible?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, mapping-class-groups, surfaces, contact-geometry

I want to understand why (if so) these two arguments are not incompatible. And if that's the case, which one is wrong.

First we have this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0510639.pdf) (by Honda, Kazez and Matic). We look at the last Lemma 6.7 which says that if $S$ is a punctured torus and $h:S \to S$ is a stabilization and right-veering, then $h$ is in $Dehn^+(S)$. I am interested in a piece of the argument used in the proof which is the following. Let $g$ be the diffeomorphism being stabilized to $h$. Then $g$ is a diffeomorphism on a annulus so it is of the form $t_\gamma^q$ where $\gamma$ is the core curve of the annulus and $t_\gamma$ is a right Dehn twist around it. And so $h$ is of the form $t_C t_\gamma^q$ where $C$ is the curve used for stabilizing. Then they say "it is easy to see that the composition $t_C t_\gamma^q$ is not right-veering unless $q > 0$."

On the other hand, we have this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.5290.pdf) (by Kazez and Roberts). And there, there is the Theorem 2.16 that says that any diffeomorphism $h:S \to S$ which is a positive stabilization and such that $S$ has connected boundary, has fractional Dehn twist coefficient between $0$ and $1/2$. (in particular it is right-veering).

Certainly, the *statement* of Lemma 6.7 in the first paper is compatible with the statement of Theorem 2.16 in the second paper. What is not compatible is the argument used in proving the first Lemma with the statement of the second result. For instance:

Consider the diffeomorphism $t_\gamma^{-5}$ on an annulus. According to the argument used in the first result the stabilization $t_C t_\gamma^{-5}$ is not right-veering  but according to the second, it is right-veering with FDTC between $0$ and $1/2$.

Comment: FDTC = 0 does not mean right-veering (or even "non-left-veering"). For example, the monodromy $\phi$ on the complement of the figure-eight knot is neither right-veering nor non-left-veering, and has FDTC = 0 (since it's amphichaeral, both $\phi$ and $\phi^{-1}$ give you F8 knot complements, so must have the same FDTC).

Comment: But in the first paper, they conclude that $t_C t_\gamma^{-5}(\beta) > \beta$ which implies negative FDTC which contradicts the second statement.

Comment: That doesn't imply negative FDTC, but non-positive FDTC.

Comment: I see. So what happens (and I think solves the riddle) is that all automorphisms of the form $t_C t_\gamma^q$ with $ q <0$ have $FDTC = 0$.